# How to partition this USB drive for installation with an easy walk through?

Tags: installation, partitioning, usb-drive

[image: Screen Shot 1]
[image: Screen Shot 2]
[image: Screen Shot 3]

I am not a *computer literate* and need to know how to partition my **USB drive** without messing up my laptop.

I already have the boot order set up properly and the USB drive already has the ISO image downloaded onto it.

I am ready for install but just do not know how to partition. I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS onto a USB. Can someone help me? I need an easy walk through please.

What I need to know is from the ***screen shots*** above do I use the **swap** drive and if so how do i partition that drive to be my drive? I am stuck up to this part on the installation process.

Yes please make a list of the steps for me.

Comment: What operating system used? Ubuntu? other linux? windows?

Comment: You can just make a LiveUSB with persistence ON. That will not be an installation but it'd work just fine. I can list down the steps if you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

First when you run the installer click Try Ubuntu. That will run Ubuntu without installing. Then plug your pendrive and type following commands :

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

This will "un-mount" the drive. Then type :

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -n <nameOfYouDrive> -I /dev/sdb1
```

This will create a ext4 partition. And replace the "nameOfYourDrive" with the name you want to give (in single quotes but not with '<>')

Then you can restart your computer and proceed with the installation. But what I would prefer is to install ubuntu 12.04LTS on another drive ie. /dev/sda2. This will not mess up your windows and your laptop!

Answer (score 1):

The downside with using Unetbootin is that the ubuntu on the USB will always revert to it's default settings and any changes or tools added will not be saved. This is not ideal if you wanted to use the USB as a rescue repair tool for Windows. Universal USB Installer works better. Here is a good "How To" from start to finish. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/

Answer (score 0):

But installing Ubuntu in a usb is very very slow !!!

But the easy way is with 2 usb, put the .iso file in one USB and use the other as the target of installation.

Follow the normal installation procedure, and only change the target to the other usb, the installation helps you with the partitioning.

Comment: You said ` installing Ubuntu in a usb is very very slow !!!` and then again suggested to install to a USB drive!!! Can you explain it?

Comment: i only warning a full instalation of ubuntu in usb is very slow. But if you need or you wanna fun you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Ubuntu onto a USB stick I think you're approaching this the wrong way. I'm assuming you already have a Windows installation you don't want to touch. Do the following.

1. Download the Ubuntu ISO you want to run, and the program `unetbootin` from sourceforge
2. With the help of `unetbootin`, place your ISO onto the USB stick. When asked, choose an amount of space you want to use for "persistence" (things you change/download while running Ubuntu from the USB). This can be all of the free space on the USB if you want.
3. When `unetbootin` is done, you now have a bootable USB stick that you can run Ubuntu from without having to install it on your computer. Changes you make while running Ubuntu from this USB should be saved on the USB, since you specified space for this in point two.

If I misunderstood you or if you have any questions, comment on this answer and I'll modify it.